# Finding minimum and maximum efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, comparison

I have two integer parameters `a` and `b`. And two integer variables `max` and `min`.
I want to assign to `max` the maximum of `a` and `b` and to `min` the minimum of the two.
I need to do this operation millions of times and so I want to optimize it. I am currently doing the following:

```
min = a < b ? a : b;
max = a > b ? a : b;
```

The problem with this is that it requires two if statements. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: In what language? Some languages allow you to do parallel assignments.

Comment: Are you allowed to use SSE intrinsics?

Comment: Yeah I guess, anything that works with VS2012 I can use.

Comment: Where do the a's and b's come from?

Comment: They were generated randomly.

Comment: Ok, I meant, what does the actual loop look like?

Comment: basically for i = 0 to a million generate the two numbers and then do something with the smaller one and do something with the larger one.

Comment: Well that's a pity. If you were getting those a's and b's in a simple way (say, each from their own array), I could easily have vectorized it for you (then again, VS2012 should be capable of doing that automatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (a < b)
{
    min = a; max = b;
}
else
{
    min = b; max = a;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that took much less time to run, Thanks!

Comment: @BenjyKessler did you enable compiler optimizations?

Comment: I am using VS 2012 and optimization is set to maximize speed.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::tie(min, max) = std::minmax(a, b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably optimizing prematurely. See what the compiler makes of it.

For a version with just one conditional, this is straightforward:-

```
if (a < b)
{
  min = a;
  max = b;
}
else
{
  min = b;
  max = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you might want to use some maths:

```
int absdiff = abs (a-b);
int sum = a+b;
max = (sum+absdiff)/2;
min = (sum-absdiff)/2;
```

You can trust compilers to optimize all that depending on the base type, you get rid of the branch and get a constant execution time (does not rely on predictors).

Edit:

sample abs integer function on Intel processors :

```
cdq 
xor eax, edx 
sub eax, edx
```

Comment: `abs()` is implemented using a conditional, typically, so you still have a branch. `int _RTLENTRYF _EXPFUNC abs(int i)
{
    return (i >= 0 ? i : -i);
}`

Comment: There are inputs for which it does not work, for example `a = 1140851080; b = -158544698`

Comment: Of course. We're talking optimization here, or else you could simply go the `a < b ? a : b` way. The max values must allow for a couple of MSBs, but who says this shoud work on a full 32 bits scale?

Comment: Well ok, just so long as we're all aware of the limitations :)

Comment: @harold after all, a mere integer substraction is already a dangerous pitfall ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 min=a;max=b;
 if(a>b) {
   max=a;
   min=b;
 } //Here you don't even need an else statement, i don't know how much time does else take but if it does then you have saved it.
```